# Finding the name of the supplier that supplies the most parts

Tags: query, max

I have the following schema:

```
Suppliers(sid: integer, sname: string, address: string)
Parts(pid: integer, pname: string, color: string)
Catalog(sid: integer, pid: integer, cost: real)
```

Now what I'm trying to do is get the name of the supplier that has the most items for sale in the Catalog. This is an example instance:

[image]

What I have so far is:

```
SELECT S.sid, COUNT(*) AS NUM
FROM Catalog C, Suppliers S
WHERE C.sid=S.sid
GROUP BY S.sid
```

Which returns each supplier id and the number of parts they supply, which sounds like a good start; however, I'm not sure where to go from there.

[image]

I tried:

```
SELECT Y.sid, MAX(Y.Num)
FROM (SELECT S.sid, COUNT(*) AS NUM
      FROM Catalog C, Suppliers S
      WHERE C.sid=S.sid
      GROUP BY S.sid) Y
```

But that returned:

```
| sid | MAX(Y.NUM) | 
+-----+------------+
| 1   |     5      |
```

...which is wrong.

I really feel like I'm over complicating this and that there is a simple solution that I'm missing. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify your DBMS, so this is ANSI SQL:

```
select sid, 
       num_products
from (
  select sid, 
         count(*) as num_products,
         dense_rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as rnk
  from catalog
  group by sid
) t
where rnk = 1;
```

If you need the information from the `supplier` table as well, you need to join it:

```
select s.sname, 
       t.num_products
from (
  select sid, 
         count(*) as num_products,
         dense_rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as rnk
  from catalog
  group by sid
) t
  join suppliers s on s.sid = t.sid
where t.rnk = 1;
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/HGL10937

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on the RDBMS you're using.  For SQL Server it would be:

```
SELECT TOP 1 main.*
FROM (SELECT S.sid, COUNT(*) AS NUM
  FROM Catalog C, Suppliers S
  WHERE C.sid=S.sid
  GROUP BY S.sid) main
ORDER BY main.NUM DESC
```

With Oracle, it would be something like:

```
SELECT TOP 1 main.*
FROM (SELECT S.sid, COUNT(*) AS NUM
  FROM Catalog C, Suppliers S
  WHERE C.sid=S.sid
  GROUP BY S.sid
ORDER BY main.NUM DESC) main
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

The issue with both of these answers is that they do not take into account if two suppliers are "tied" for first.  with SQL Server you'd use something like ROW_NUMBER or RANK to take care of that.  Depends on your RDBMS and your specific needs.

Comment: `row_number()` or `rank()` are available in Oracle as well (in fact **way** longer then they are available in SQL Server)